# from vector equation to cartesian equation of a line

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a doubt on why the vector line $r:(x,y,z)=\lambda(1,1,-1)+\mu(0,1,1)$ can be written as $2x-y+z=0$ and why $r:(x,y,z)=\lambda(1,1,-1)+\mu(2,-1,1)$ can be written as $y+z=0$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first vector equation can be written, in component form, as

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right){}={}\left(\begin{array}{c}\lambda\\\lambda\\-\lambda\end{array}\right){}+{}\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\ \mu\\ \mu\end{array}\right){}={}\left(\begin{array}{c}\lambda\\ \mu{}+{}\lambda\\ \mu-\lambda\end{array}\right)\,.
$$

By using this, substituting for $x,y$ and $z$ in what follows , we can see that $2x-y+z{}={}0$ must be the correct equation, because

$$
2x{}-{}y{}+z{}\,\,\,=\,\,\,{}2\lambda-(\mu+\lambda){}+{}(\mu-\lambda)\,\,\,=\,\,\,{}0\,.
$$

The same sort of reasoning can be used to prove the other equation. I encourage you to try it and see.

**EDIT:**

For a direct derivation, we solve the following linear system using [row reduction](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/linearsystems/) 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\1&1\\-1&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}\lambda\\\mu\end{array}\right){}={}\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)\,.
$$

This results in

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}\lambda\\\mu\end{array}\right){}={}\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\x+z\\2x-y+z\end{array}\right)\,,
$$

where we deduce the equation of the plane from the last line.

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: @AliMostafa, Please let me know which parts of the answer you understand and which parts you don't.

Comment: how do I substitute $x,y,z$?

Comment: @AliMostafa, from the vector equation we know that $x=\lambda$, $y=\mu+\lambda$ and $z=\mu-\lambda$. Use these values of $x ,y$ and $z$ in "$2x-y+z$" and simplify the algebra. You will see that the $\lambda$ and $\mu$ terms will all cancel out to become zero. This means that the vector satisfies the equation of the plane; that's what I did.

Comment: But if I don't have the cartesian equation, how can I obtain it?

Comment: @AliMostafa, please see edit.

Comment: i don't understandd what you did...

Comment: can you tell me the solution step by step? thank you very much!

Comment: @AliMostafa, I performed row operations on the Matrix equation. Unfortunately, I cannot teach you row reduction (please see the link I included) in a single post on this website;  you really need to learn that separately from either your Mathematics teachers or from good books on Linear-algebra. If, however, you already know row reduction then please try it out (I have told you the answer), and if you get stuck you can post a question on this site saying exactly where you are stuck; you will get helpful responses. I encourage you to try it yourself, this is the best way to learn Mathematics.